# Mass File Comparison

Tags: windows, files, application

I have a folder that has over 1000 text files in it and I need to check if they all have the same contents, they are all the same size so I can't tell that way - does anyone know of a mass file comparison too that will accept many files as an input and highlight any changes that differ from the first file that was loaded?

OS=Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

md5sum is probably easiest, then compare the results. You can script this if it's done often but as a one off you can just do the below by hand.

On linux:
`md5sum [first file]`

Take that hash (via copy/paste) and:

`md5sum * | sort | grep -v [first hash]`

This'll leave anything that has a different hash value.

Comment: Is there an equivalent in windows, I know I could probably use cgywin, but I hope I could just find an app that I could point to a folder and get what I wanted?

Comment: Hmmm. to me that's filed under "here be dragons" :) http://www.pc-tools.net/win32/md5sums/ for the md5 bit, dunno about grep equivalent in windows. http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm maybe.

Comment: The idea was sound, I found something called md5deep that worked for me.

Comment: I'd use rsync (automatically handles recursion) rather than running md5sum repeatedly - but then I don't have to suffer MSWindows on my servers.

Comment: Cygwin has all these utilities. I recommend it to every windows power user.